# Getting the lat and lon of nearest phones

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, blackberry

I have to get the location (lat & lon) of the phones near my phone. Is there any way to do this. If so please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

No. Android phones do not broadcast their location to the entire world. You could try to find the location of phones *with your software installed* near your phone, by storing coordinates on a server and doing a query using R-trees or quadtrees or something, but you can't query for *all* android phones.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best (and potentially only) option would be to leverage off of the [Google Latitude API](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/latitude/index.html). Users of Latitude and/or your app will broadcast their locations, which will then be discoverable for your app via the Latitude API.

Comment: Is it possible to query for the nearby phones locations using the Google latitude API?

Comment: see this article: http://stronglyemergent.com/2011/locating-design-in-latitude-find-my-friends-and-yelp/, e.g. "you can have your Latitude location displayed as part of the Google Chat interface"